# Consolidate repeated prefix

Tags: shell-script, string, text-formatting

I have a log file like:

```
Bug123:c:SomeComment
Bug222:c:SomeOtherComment
Bug123:c:SecondComment
```

I need to produce:

```
Bug123
    SomeComment
    SecondComment
Bug222
    SomeComment
```

Using bash, I can't seem to think of a way of accomplishing this in a simple way. Any ideas?

Comment: Reminds me of the `git shortlog` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {comments[$1][NR]=$3} END {for (bug in comments) { print bug; for (comment in comments[bug]) { print "    ",comments[bug][comment] } } }  ' /path/to/input
Bug123
     SomeComment
     SecondComment
Bug222
     SomeOtherComment
```

This works by setting up a multi-dimensional array as it reads the input file, and then traversing the resultant data in the order the "bugs" are seen.  With some small tweaks, this could be modified to sort outer-level array.

Comment: I gotta learn how to awk. No idea how it works, but looks nifty.

Comment: It's kind of like `vim` in that is looks very obtuse at first but once you sink your teeth in, it's very quick to learn and can be a _very_ powerful tool.  See also `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun way to do it in `vi` (or, actually, in `ex` if you omit the leading colons for each command):

```
:%!awk -F: '{a[$1];print} END {for (i in a) {print i}}'
:v/:/m0
:%!sort -st: -k1,1
:%s/^.*:/\t/
```

Explanation:

The Awk command prints every line as-is and dumps a list of all unique first fields at the end of your file.

The `v` command `m`oves to line 0 (the start of the file) all the lines that *don't* have any colon.  (In other words, the list of first fields output from `awk`.)

The `sort` command does a `s`table sort, preserving the order of the lines other than arranging them according to first field.  (We already moved the "header" fields to the start of the file.)

Then the `s`ubstitute command turns the prefix of each non-header line into a tab.

---

Result on your provided input:

```
Bug123
    SomeComment
    SecondComment
Bug222
    SomeOtherComment
```

---

Additional explanations:

`:` (colon) is what you type in `vi` to begin an `ex`-style command.

`%` is an address range in [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).  It means "apply the following action/command to all lines in the buffer (file)."

When used with an address, `!` begins a "filter" in `ex`: the lines specified by the address are fed as input to the specified external command, and are replaced in the buffer by the output of that command.

`-F:` sets the Awk field separator.

`{}` (curly braces) are used in Awk to surround commands to be run.  Since there is no *Awk* address preceding the curly braces (within the single quotes), the actions in the curly braces are applied to every line of input.

`a[$1]` creates an array element using the first field of the current line (`$1`) as the index.  Since it doesn't say `= "whatever"`, the array element has no *value*, but that doesn't matter; we just want the array to contain that element.

`;` terminates that Awk command.

`print` is the Awk command to print the current line (by default) or whatever arguments are passed (as in the later `print i`).

`END` tags the action block (in curly braces) to be executed after all input (to Awk) is processed.

The `for` loop prints all the indices of the array called `a`.  Which are the de-duplicated first fields of the log file, in no specific order.

So much for the Awk command.

The `v` command is an `ex` command which is the opposite of the `g`lobal command.  `g` performs an action on *all lines matching* a certain pattern.  `v` performs the specified action on all lines NOT matching the given pattern.

`/` starts and ends the pattern.  Which is just `:` in this case.

`m` means "move."  So `:v/:/m0` in `vi` moves all lines which don't contain any colons to the top of the file.

The rest of the commands should be pretty clear.  :)

Comment: How do I run this in a bash script?

Answer (score 2):

perl one-liner

```
perl -MList::Util=uniq -F: -lane '
        push @keys, $F[0];
        push @{ $comment{$F[0]} }, $F[2];
    } END { 
        for $key (uniq @keys) {
            print $key;
            print "    $_" for @{$comment{$key}};
        }
' file
```

Comment: It's a one-liner, for large values of 1 :)

Comment: Sure it is. One command. The newlines are just plain characters inside a single quoted argument for the -e option. And my 1's are the biggest ones, the best ones. Yuge.